publishing on set_link_state gazebo
I'm trying to publish some angular velocity to one of my drone rotor
However the moment I publish, my rotor teleports to origin, and this is not only for this model, doesn't matter what model or what link I choose the moment I publish that particular link teleports to origin and comes back when stop publishing,
Here's the code I'm using to publish the state,
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rospy
from gazebo_msgs.msg import LinkState
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist, Pose

def set_link_state():
    rospy.init_node('rotate_drone_rotor', anonymous=True)
    pub = rospy.Publisher('/gazebo/set_link_state', LinkState, queue_size=10)

    rate = rospy.Rate(10)  # Publish at 10 Hz

    link_state_msg = LinkState()
    link_state_msg.link_name = 'iris::rotor_0'  # Adjust this to match the exact name of your rotor link

    # Set the pose to avoid teleporting to the origin
    link_state_msg.pose = Pose()  # Defaults to (0,0,0) position and (0,0,0,1) orientation
    
    # Set only angular velocity
    link_state_msg.twist = Twist()
    link_state_msg.twist.linear.x = 0.0
    link_state_msg.twist.linear.y = 0.0
    link_state_msg.twist.linear.z = 0.0
    link_state_msg.twist.angular.x = 0.0
    link_state_msg.twist.angular.y = 0.0  # Angular velocity in radians per second
    link_state_msg.twist.angular.z = 0.01

    rospy.loginfo("Publishing to /gazebo/set_link_state")

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        pub.publish(link_state_msg)
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        set_link_state()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass


Are you publishing tf between the joints of your drone?
